# Как изменить цвет Windows 10 используя cmd или PowerShell?

Tags: node.js, cmd, windows-10, bat, powershell

[image: цвета Windows]
Решил сделать WEB обои для Wallpaper Engine, автоматически подгоняющие цвет интерфейса системы под цвет обоев, используя локальный веб-сервер на Node.js для исполнения команд cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменение цвета возможно только из Registry, я бы не советовал играть с ним. Написать можете на любом, языке который вы знаете. Тут лежат настроки цвета для Windows:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors
```

Чтобы зайти посмотреть вашу цветовую схему нажмите сочетание клавишь `Windows+R`, введите в открывшемся окне комманду `regedit` и нажмите "ОК". Дальше по дереву списка вы сможете найти эти настройки.